# JHipster OAuth2 Suddenly Does not Show Entity Menu After Successfull Okta Login

Tags: jhipster, okta

I have an application which was working perfectly fine; however, today when I tried to login to the JHipster app using my Okta credentials, I do not get the entities menu.  There are no logs in the Browser console and on the server side of any error.  This just started happening - no code was changed.  I am running JHipster version 7.6.0.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you looked which user roles you get?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou is correct. Make sure you have a `groups` claim added to your access token. See JHipster's [Okta docs](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#okta) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @GaëlMarziou and Matt Raible.  I checked the Authorities and the group claims.  They were correct.  The problem was that my database configuration changed on Heroku and I was pointing to a nonexistent database.  After I changed the database configuration, I was able to see the Entities and Administration menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gateway was not connecting to the database, due to incorrect configuration information.  Once the correct database connection was entered, the Entities and Administration menus appeared again.  Heroku had updated their databases and I needed to enter the new connection information.